# Python HTTP Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, http, urllib, weather-api, google-weather-api

I am a bit of a Python Newbie, and I've just been trying to get some code working.

Below is the code, and also the nasty error I keep getting.

> ```
> import pywapi import string
>
> google_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_google('Brisbane')
>
> print google_result 
> def getCurrentWather():
>   city = google_result['forecast_information']['city'].split(',')[0]
>   print "It is " + string.lower(google_result['current_conditions']['condition']) + " and
>   " + google_result['current_conditions']['temp_c'] + " degree
>   centigrade now in "+ city+".\n\n"
>   return "It is " + string.lower(google_result['current_conditions']['condition']) + " and
>   " + google_result['current_conditions']['temp_c'] + " degree
>   centigrade now in "+ city
>
> def getDayOfWeek(dayOfWk):
>     #dayOfWk = dayOfWk.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
>     return dayOfWk.lower()
>
> def getWeatherForecast():
>    #need to translate from sun/mon to sunday/monday
>    dayName = {'sun': 'Sunday', 'mon': 'Monday', 'tue': 'Tuesday', 'wed': 'Wednesday', '    thu': 'Thursday', 'fri': 'Friday', 'sat':
>    'Saturday', 'sun': 'Sunday'}
>
> forcastall = []
> for forecast in google_result['forecasts']:
>     dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(forecast['day_of_week']);
>     print " Highest is " + forecast['high'] + " and "+ "Lowest is " + forecast['low'] + " on " +  dayName[dayOfWeek]
>     forcastall.append(" Highest is " + forecast['high'] + " and "+ "Lowest is " + forecast['low'] + " on " +  dayName[dayOfWeek])
> return forcastall
> ```

Now is the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\JAVIS\JAISS-master\first.py", line 5, in
> <module>
> import Weather   File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\JAVIS\JAISS-master\Weather.py", line 4, in
> <module>
> google_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_google('Brisbane')   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywapi.py", line 51, in
> get_weather_from_google
> handler = urllib2.urlopen(url)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
> return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
> response = meth(req, response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
> 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
> return self._call_chain(*args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
> raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
> ```

Thanks for any help I can get!

Comment: Please format you code according to Pythonic conventions and then we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 403 error doesn't come from your code but from Google. Google lets you know that you don't have permission to access the resource you were requesting, in this case the weather API, because it has been discontinued (403 technically stands for Forbidden, they could also have gone for 404 Not Found or 410 Gone).

For more information, read http://thenextweb.com/google/2012/08/28/did-google-just-quietly-kill-private-weather-api/

Other than that, your code is correct.

Answer (score 3):

It's not your error. Google discontinued its weather API a few time ago.

If you need a free weather API I would recommend using the service I'm building, Metwit [weather API](http://metwit.com/weather-api/). This is the simplest working example using [metwit-weather](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/metwit-weather):

```
from metwit import Metwit
weather = Metwit.weather.get(location_lat=45.45, location_lng=9.18)
```

Further examples are found here: http://soup.metwit.com/post/45997437810/python-weather-by-metwit

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python3 and having the same issue. I found that Google blocks urllib that doesnt overwrite the User-Agent and Accept-Encoding headers.

The headers it used for a test search:

```
GET /search?q=f1+2015 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: close
User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.4
Host: 127.0.0.1:8076
```

I put 'Accept-Encoding' to '' and 'User-Agent' to 'testing' and the 403 error stopped.